# Mocha only running one test file

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, babeljs

My Mocha tests were working fine, but when I added a new module (and test), mocha stopped running all of my test files and now only runs the single new test.

My test script:

```
env NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:$PWD/src mocha --recursive --compilers js:babel-core/register src/**/*.test.js --require babel-polyfill
```

My project is structured like this:

```
/src
  /components
    /component-name
      index.js
      component.js
      component-name.test.js
      style.scss
  /util
    /module-name
      index.js
      module-name.test.js
  /some-other-module
    index.js
    some-other-module.test.js
```

I had several tests in `/components` and `/util` and everything worked fine, but when I place a module into `/src` (like `/some-other-module`) with a `.test.js` file in it, Mocha only runs that test file and none of the others.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put single quotes around the pattern you pass to Mocha to prevent it being interpreted by your shell: `'src/**/*.test.js'`

What happens is that, without the quotes, your shell tries to expand that pattern and is successful. The result of expansion is `src/some-other-module/some-other-module.test.js` and this is what is passed to Mocha.

Before you created that file, the shell still tried to expand the pattern but was not successful and left the pattern as-is. So Mocha got `src/**/*.test.js`, which Mocha itself interpreted as a glob.

In case you wonder, in Bash, unless the `globstar` option is turned on, `**` is equivalent to `*`.

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly. I assumed `**` would work because it does work in my shell (ZShell), but it appears `package.json` scripts are run with Bash.

Comment: How to set a pattern in `mocha` config?

Comment: Note that single quotes won't work in Windows. There you'll have to escape the double quotes in package.json in order for the pattern to be passed correctly to mocha: `\"src/**/*.test.js\"`