# Mocha only runs one test case

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm using mocha to test api's created using node.js. I've written two test file and the file structure is as follows

```
server/
├── connect/
|   ├── test
|       |── root.spec.ts
|
└── model/
    ├──test
       ├──abc.spec.ts
```

The script written in package.json is as follows.

```
"test": "mocha server/**/**/**.spec.ts --exit"
```

Now when I when I run the command `npm test` in the terminal inside the `model directory`. It shows content present inside the `root.spec.ts`. How do I run the `abc.spec.ts` i.e a single file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocha only running one test file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303370/mocha-only-running-one-test-file)

Comment: I tried this solution as well. But it still runs only the root.spec.ts